# Thin parentheses bracket

Tags: brackets, math-fonts

How do I typeset the bracket/parentheses form the second equation.

[image]

I have been searching the internet and gone through various mathfonts but did not find the right one. Can someone please help me to find one or to explain how to obtain the required brackets. Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but getting bad output is not easy with TeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
F(x)=\begin{pmatrix} x/2 & 0 \\ 0 & x^2 \end{pmatrix}
=\left\lgroup\begin{matrix} x/2 & 0 \\ 0 & x^2 \end{matrix}\right\rgroup
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I tried that, but this is not what I am looking for. The brackets are very thick here.

Comment: @Kumarm As I said, it's difficult to produce bad output like in the bottom matrix of your picture.

Answer (score 3):

seems a bit of a strange request but, modifying egreg's example, as you did not provide one...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
F(x)=\begin{pmatrix} x/2 & 0 \\ 0 & x^2 \end{pmatrix}
=\mbox{\tiny$\left(\mbox{\normalsize$\begin{matrix} x/2 & 0 \\ 0 & x^2 \end{matrix}$}\right)$}
\]

\end{document}
```