# Make new delimiter using Tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mathtools, delimiters

I am interested in creating a new paired delimiter using tikzpictures I defined. There has to be something easy I'm missing, but hours of searching has proved fruitless. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\pewl{\hspace{.075cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, baseline=1mm, line width=.23mm]
\draw (0mm,3.25mm) -- (0mm,1mm);
\draw (0mm,3.25mm) arc (180:90:.8mm);
\draw (0mm,1mm) arc (180:270:.8mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\def\pewr{\hspace{-.01cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, baseline=1mm, line width=.23mm]
\draw (0mm,3.25mm) -- (0mm,1mm);
\draw (0mm,3.25mm) arc (0:90:.8mm);
\draw (0mm,1mm) arc (0:-90:.8mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pew}{\pewl}{\pewr}

\begin{document}

$$
\pewl M\pewr \pewl g\pewr \pewl f\pewr 
\pew{M} \pew{g} \pew{\sum}
$$

\end{document}
```

which begets:

[image: Failed new tikzpicture delimiters.]

and an error saying:

> Missing delimiter (. inserted).

I'm on Overleaf, if that's relevant somehow. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Your braces remind me on `\left\lgroup ... \right\rgroup`. For examples see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503249/

Comment: The code you included does not give the error you claim. The missing delimiter would kick in if you use `\pew*` and not `\pew`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to [want an auto-scaling paired delimiter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701956/make-new-delimiter-using-tikzpicture/701965?noredirect=1#comment1745937_701965) out of the tikz drawing you made. This can be done by

1. Making the height and depth of the parentheses adjustable
2. Measuring the content by saving it to a box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% inserted extra 1mu before and after the symbol, can be adjusted.
% this is in addition to the spacing inserted by mathopen and mathclose
\newcommand\@pewl[2]{\ensuremath{\mathopen{\mkern1mu\relax%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, baseline=1mm, line width=.23mm]
\draw (0mm,1mm+#1) -- (0mm,1mm-#2);
\draw (0mm,1mm+#1) arc (180:90:.8mm);
\draw (0mm,1mm-#2) arc (180:270:.8mm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
}}

\newcommand\@pewr[2]{\ensuremath{\mathclose{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, baseline=1mm, line width=.23mm]
\draw (0mm,1mm+#1) -- (0mm,1mm-#2);
\draw (0mm,1mm+#1) arc (0:90:.8mm);
\draw (0mm,1mm-#2) arc (0:-90:.8mm);
\end{tikzpicture}\mkern1mu\relax}
}}

\newsavebox{\pew@inner}
\newlength\pew@ht
\newlength\pew@dp
\newcommand\pew[1]{%
        \text{\savebox{\pew@inner}{$#1$}%
                \pew@ht=\ht\pew@inner\relax%
                \pew@dp=\dp\pew@inner\relax%
                \ifdim\pew@ht<1.5ex\relax% Set a minimum height of 1.5ex
                        \global\pew@ht=1.5ex\relax
                \fi
        \@pewl{\pew@ht}{\pew@dp}\usebox{\pew@inner}\@pewr{\pew@ht}{\pew@dp}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
        \pew{M} \pew{g} \pew{k} \pew{\frac12} \pew{\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1+ \frac12}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a literal deity. Holy moly thank you so much!

Comment: I was able to make this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703836/how-can-i-change-the-catcode-within-a-command-then-reference-input-using-the-ne using your help!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

> **Don't use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` with objects that are not scalable delimiters**

Your code actually runs into two different sorts of problem.

1. If you used `\pew{M}`, you should see an error about a missing `{`.

   This is a cryptic error, and results from how `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` treats the unstarred version with no optional argument. In this case, the code essentially just expands to `\mathopen\pewl M\mathclose\pewr`. <strike>Why this breaks I don't really know, but is a case where `\mathopen#1` and `\mathopen{#1}` behave differently.</strike> This is a problem because `\mathopen` is a TeX primitive that expects what follows to expand to either a single character or to a group. As you defined it, `\pewl` is neither.

   This could be "solved" if you just declare your `\pewl` and `\pewr` appropriately as objects of mathopen/close types to start with. E.g., you can just define `\pewl` as `\mathopen{\hspace{0.075cm}...}`. You should do this anyway *independently of the rest of this answer* since if you are creating delimiters, they should be typeset following rules of typesetting delimiters, and not that of ordinary math atoms.
2. If you used `\pew[\big]{M}` or `\pew*{M}`, you see the error about missing delimiter and the insertion of `.`

   Somewhere (after a lot of expansions) TeX will encounter something that looks like `\left\pewl`. But this would only be meaningful if `\pewl` is a scalable delimiter. As `\pewl` is not such a thing ([being a scalable delimiter is a quality of particular symbols defined in the font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183954/new-left-right-delimiters)), `\left` complains.

**Solution:**

1. As mentioned above, define `\pewl` and `\pewr` as `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` atoms.
2. Instead of using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, just use `\newcommand` to define `\pew`.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful response. I can tell that these are problems, however, what I would love to do is DEFINE a new scalable delimiter.

Comment: You should first read: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183954/), [this too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251999/), [this one also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422462/), [this other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202750/), and [this final one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109699/). In your case it would almost certainly be easier to skip making it work with the mathtools construction of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and just define the scaling yourself.